# VS2019 ASP.NET(MVC) - How to Login with only Email and Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2019

I made a User object that contains 7 properties when you create a new user.
The problem is that when I want to login - I want to enter only Email and Password, and when the data goes to the UsersController to the Login function(POST, and GET) it doesn't process and skip the whole "if (ModelState.IsValid)" because it didn't get the rest of the data(because the function only gets the Email and Password and not the other values).
So my question is, How can I do that even if my model has 7 properties(attributes), only the Email and Password will be taken into consideration "if (ModelState.IsValid)" and log me in.

I hope I could manage to explain my problem, my English isn't that good I know that.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFZ4.png)

My User model:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ourProject.Models
{
    public enum UserType
    {
        Guest,
        Client,
        rManager,
        Admin
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert phone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Birthday Date")]
        public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set; }

        //one to one
        public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }

        public UserType Type { get; set; } = UserType.Guest;
    }
}
```

My UsersController:

```
// GET: Users/Login
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Users/Login
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind("Id,Email,Password")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var q = from u in _context.User
                        where u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password
                        select u;

                if (q.Count() > 0)
                {

                    //_context.Add(user);
                    //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = "Username and/or password are incorrect.";
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFZ4.png)

Comment: I don't think you should use the very same `User` object. Instead, create another `Login` object with only user and password and take that as a parameter. You can return a `User` after you validate and can access the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate User into 2 classes:

```
public class UserLogin
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class User:UserLogin
    {
      
        [Display(Name = "Full name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert phone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Birthday Date")]
        public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set; }

        //one to one
        public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }

        public UserType Type { get; set; } = UserType.Guest;
    }
```

and action

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLogin userLogin)
```

another way is  to assign default values to required properties and create hidden fields in view

```
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
           var model= new User{ Name="Unknown", PhoneNumber="123-123-4567" }
            return View(model);
        }
.....

//view

<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Name" value=@Model.Name"  />
```